# always getting a default route - Angular 4

Tags: angular, path, routes

I have the following code:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]    },
 // Lazy Loading (preloads) so I wont have to LOAD the new code chunk
{ path: 'highlights', loadChildren: './highlights/highlights.module#HighlightsModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'news', loadChildren: './news/news.module#NewsModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
{
    path: 'not-found',
    component: ErrorPageComponent,
 data: { message: 'Page was not found' }
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/not-found' } // must be last
];
```

My login '/login' route is outsourced to a module (AuthModule) with a routing module (AuthRoutingModule).

My routing const inside AuthRoutingModule is:

```
const authRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
];
```

The problem Occures only if this **path** in **appRoutes** exists:

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/not-found' }
```

Otherwise it works fine.

I do not understand it. I always get not-found as if **'/login'** is not recognized.

**'/login'** is exported with the outsourced Modules i mentioned above.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are the route definitions that you use when you call `RouterModule.forRoot()` then It will always navigate to not-found if you try to navigate to `root/login`. There is no definition for that path in those routes...

If you have another module, where there is a definition for that path, then you need to load that module into the routes that you use for RouterModule.forRoot()

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. If your setup is proper then 
try to resolve all the file import errors/minor errors  in the components .